# Missing type map configuration or unsupported mapping in Automapper 5.0.2

Tags: c#, odata, automapper-5

I am using AutoMapper in my OData API. I found many questions with the same title and also tried all solutions, but my problem not get resolved. I am using latest AutoMapper version 5.0.2. Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Here is my code :

Startup.cs

```
public static partial class Startup
{
    public static void ConfigureApp(IAppBuilder appBuilder)
    {
       ConfigureAuth(appBuilder);
        AutoMapperWebConfiguration.Configure();
        Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        // Config OData       
        ConfigureOData(config);
     }
}
```

AutoMapperWebConfiguration.cs

```
public static class AutoMapperWebConfiguration
{
    public static void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.Initialize(
            config =>
            {
                config.CreateMap<ContractType, ContractTypeDto>().ReverseMap();
            });         

    }
}
```

ContractTypeController.cs

```
public class ODataContractTypeController : ODataController
{
    [ODataRoute]
    [EnableQuery]
    public IHttpActionResult Get()
    {
        var returnResult = db.ContractTypes;          
        var result = Mapper.Map<ContractTypeDto>(returnResult);

        return result; 
    }
}
```

Thank You

Comment: Are you using EF? Because if so, then the type isn't `ContractType`, it's `ContractType0123456789etc` as EF proxies the class. If so, call `ToList()` on the contract types to get the actual class, or use [Projection](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Projection)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to map enumerable of T, instead of just T. Try this

```
[ODataRoute]
[EnableQuery]
public IHttpActionResult Get()
{
    var returnResult = db.ContractTypes.ToArray();
    var result = Array.ConvertAll(returnResult, Mapper.Map<ContractTypeDto>);       

    return result;     
}
```

Comment: Or `Mapper.Map<List<ContractTypeDto>>(returnResult.ToList());`?

Comment: If I use ToList or ToArray then it will be work but I am working on OData project so I getting DbSet i.e creating just query here : var returnResult = db.ContractTypes; and it hit database when dispose DB. So I cant use ToList and ToArray here.

Comment: You will hit db in anycase. If not explicitly (via ToList or Toarray) then implicitly (AutoMapper will enumerate dbset to do mapping). So you can safely call ToArray.

Comment: When I am using ToList or ToArray then it takes huge time. When I return just entity then it takes 4 to 5 seconds but when I map entity to DTO using ToList/ToArray() then its take 1,4 minute. So please can you explain why its happening ?

Comment: What do you mean by "When I return just entity..."? A real call for data begins when you call ToList/ToArray. In this line `var returnResult = db.ContractTypes;` no call occurs.

Comment: When I return entity then real call begins  for data when I  dispose database. So without using ToList/ToAarry I can return entity.

Comment: Not yet, currently I am just returning entity.

Comment: It is really strange that the mapping process takes minute and a half. May be you have there millions and millions entities to map?